# Python - Substring and Reverse Function

Tags: python, substring

I have this code in SQL:

```
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @STRING = 'Making this course amazing - 3h'

SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@STRING),1,charindex('-',reverse(@STRING))-1))
```

I'm trying to adapt this to Python, but without success. The code I tried was:

```
import re
Task = 'Making this course amazing - 3h'
print(re.findall("-" ,Task, flags=re.I))
```

But it gives me '-' only and I want every which are right from '-'

Comment: `Task.split('-')[1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need regex for that. Use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

```
Task.split('-')[1]
```

By the way `Task` is not an accepted name for a variable in Python, according to the convention. Use `task` instead.